# How to put a java3d-based applet onto a website?

Tags: java, applet, java-3d

I got a java3d based applet, and I want to try to put it onto my local host. However, the applet not work at all, I think it may be caused by the special library "java3d" included. I do appreciate if anyone has solution to this problem!

Comment: Any error messages in the java console?

Comment: Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.